# Slow NSWindow image drawing during live resize

Tags: cocoa, optimization, graphics, nswindow, throttling

I have a simple test Cocoa application, running under XCode 4.5 on OS X 10.7.5. The application contains a single NSWindow. The content view of the window is a custom view, whose drawRect method generates an image (very quickly) and draws it in the view using CGContextDrawImage. No scaling or any other manipulation.

I've been timing the drawing using UpTime() calls. The drawing operation is initially fairly fast, about 5 msec. However, during live resize, CGContextDrawImage takes about an even second (something like 1020 msec) before it returns. I tried it on a slow computer running 10.7.5, a fast one running 10.6.8, with small and large windows, with or without the cursor showing; always the same result. Actual CPU usage during drawing is quite low. It feels as if the system throttles the redraw during live resize, and at no other time.

If I just fill the rect with a solid color I don't get this effect.

Any idea what's going on?